# Hypothesis: An injection from polygons into $SO(2) \times S_n$

Tags: gr.group-theory, projective-geometry, plane-geometry, polygons, transformation-groups

I have stumbled upon a possible representation of polygons by a concise description of their behaviour under rotation. I would like to know more about it and, obviously, if it is actually a bijection. I will be somewhat informal to epxlain things more intuitively.

Consider the following: We call $\mathcal{P}_n$ the set of polygons in the plane with n points that do not self-intersect.
Furthermore, we want the vetrices of the polygons to have pairwise different x-components.
This means no two vertices can lie above eachother.

We can represent a $P \in \mathcal{P}$ as a tuple:
\begin{equation}
  P = ((x_1,y_1),...,(x_n,y_n)),
\end{equation}
where connecting the points in order yields the boundary of the polygon.

Now we define $\sigma(P) \in S_n$ as the permutation that is the "ascending ordering of $(x_1, ..., x_n)$". (the permutation that returns the ordered list).

If we let $\tau \in SO(2)$ be a rotation, then $\tau(P) \in \mathcal{P}$ will always be the case except for a finite number of rotations $\tau_1, ..., \tau_k$. This is the case because the polygon has finitely many points, so two poimts vertically align only for finitely many rotations.

For one of these $1 \leq j \leq k$, we can't define $\sigma(\tau_j(P))$ because the rotated polygon 's vertices' x-values are not pairwise different.
However, for a small $\epsilon > 0$ we know that
\begin{equation}
 (\tau_j + \epsilon)(P) \in \mathcal{P} \text{ and } (\tau_j - \epsilon)(P) \in \mathcal{P}.
\end{equation}
This means that we can define a $\sigma_j \in S_n$ as the permutation
\begin{equation}
 \sigma_j := \sigma((\tau_j + \epsilon)(P)) \; \sigma((\tau_j - \epsilon)(P))^{-1}.
\end{equation}
Basically, $\sigma_j$ is the permutation that describes how $\sigma(\tau(P))$ changes at $\tau_j$.
Now our representation of $P$ is:
\begin{equation}
   \mathcal{R}(P) = \{(\tau_1, \sigma_1), ..., (\tau_k, \sigma_k)\} \subset SO(2) \times S_n.
\end{equation}

Now my question is: How much of $P$ can we recover from $\mathcal{R}(P)$? Is the representation unique up to congruence? In other words: Is
\begin{equation}
 \mathcal{R}: \mathcal{P} / \sim \quad \longrightarrow SO(2) \times S_n
\end{equation}
an injection for some $\sim$?

I think this might be true in some way because if you know that $(\tau, \sigma) \in \mathcal{R}(P)$, then you know that after rotating by exactly $\tau$ you can study $\sigma$ and know that all the points whose position in the permutation changed must have been on a straight line.
This might be sufficient to recover enough "straight-line-relations" between the points to construct the polygon (up to translation, rotation and scale, of course).

The use would be the following: When we have a transformation of polygons $f: \mathcal{P} \longrightarrow \mathcal{P}$, it might be the case that we can do this:
\begin{equation}
 \mathcal{f}: \mathcal{R}(\mathcal{P}) \overset{\text{recover}}{\longrightarrow} \mathcal{P} \overset{f}{\longrightarrow} \mathcal{P} \overset{\mathcal{R}}{\longrightarrow} \mathcal{R}(\mathcal{P}).
\end{equation}
This can then be studied algebraically.

Comment: If, instead of polygons, you just consider a discrete set of points, then it sounds close to Goodman & Pollack's *circular sequence of permutations.* A source is the [*Handbook of Discrete & Computational Geometry*](https://www.routledge.com/Handbook-of-Discrete-and-Computational-Geometry-Third-Edition/Toth-ORourke-Goodman/p/book/9781498711395?utm_source=crcpress.com&utm_medium=referral), Chapter 5: [PDF Chap.5](http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~felsner/Paper/pseudol.pdf).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems like Theorem 5.2.2 is surprisingly close to being an answer to my question.

Comment: Yes. The language is quite different, but the underlying concepts appear to be analogous.

Comment: For simplicity, restrict to polys with no parallel sides. If I am correct, the $\sigma_k$'s (or transpositions) give the order in which line segments at angle $\theta_k$'s (with x-axis) join together to form a polygon. Let the lengths of line segments be $r_k$'s. WLOG, the first line segment starts at origin along the x-axis. This leads to the two linear equations (over $r_k\geq 0,~\forall k$) - net displacement along x and y axis must be zero. This under-determined system of linear equations will likely have multiple solutions, which might not all be congruent to each other. Hope this helps.

Comment: The title is misleading because you produce from each polygon a subset of $SO(2)\times S_n$.